# How to rollback DB changes on a Spring project using Hibernate, JUnit 3.8 and DbUnit

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit, dbunit

So I have a Spring project which uses Hibernate as ORM and is unfortunately bound to JUnit 3.8 (to support the old JSFUnit framework).

As part of unit testing, I wish to access database logic, while keeping my test database intact at the end of the run.

I figured DbUnit would be useful, and I'm searching for a working example integrating all these technologies, whereby test data gets refreshed for each JUnit method.

I really appreciate any help on this, especially since I have already spent much time looking at examples running on JUnit 4 (and not 3.8). Thanks !

Edit: I believe using class ***AbstractJUnit38SpringContextTests*** by Spring is the way to go, since it is the latest class made for JUnit 3.8 to help us in such cases.

Comment: Afaik, if you use @Transactional and the Spring JUnit Runner, Spring should automatically recognize that it's in test mode and rollback the transactions...

Comment: Yes, but as I understood, the Spring JUnit Runner is for JUnit 4 and I'm depending on JUnit 3.8 instead.

Comment: Ah, yeah, my bad. Never needed the abstract class for spring there, but as far as the documentation says, it seems to be the way to go...

Answer (score 0):

We dropped support for JUnit 3.8 in Spring Framework 4.0.

However, if you are still using Spring 3.2.x you can extend from the [AbstractTransactionalJUnit38SpringContextTests](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.15.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit38/AbstractTransactionalJUnit38SpringContextTests.html) base class.

Since you're using DbUnit, you may also be interested in the third-party [DbUnitTestExecutionListener](https://springtestdbunit.github.io/spring-test-dbunit/).

Regards,

Sam *(author of the Spring TestContext Framework)*

Comment: Thanks. I just need a way to change the Spring Context file location now. Unfortunately my test case already extends class ServletTestCase (of Apache Cactus) which works with JSFUnit to run my test case on the Tomcat running in eclipse. So, I cannot extend a second class (such as AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests maybe which allows me to change the context through overriding a method named 'getConfigLocations'). Glad I got your attention :)